# If statement with appending file

Tags: java, try-catch, randomaccessfile

Need to write a program that removes the last character of a file only if it's not an int / number. This what I have so far.

```
import java.io.*;

 public class RemoveTurn{
     public static void main(String[] arg){
         try{
         RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("test.txt", "rw");
         long length = raf.length();
         System.out.println("File Length="+raf.length());
         //supposing that last line is of 8 
         raf.setLength(length - 1);
         System.out.println("File Length="+raf.length());
         raf.close();
         }catch(Exception ex){
         ex.printStackTrace();
     }
   }
}
```

Program skeleton was taken from: [happycodings.com](http://java.happycodings.com/core-java/code66.html)

Comment: what do you mean by "not a number of an int value"? Do you mean just if the last character is a number?

Comment: have you heard of apache FileUtils?

Comment: That was a typo, my bad, editing it now.

Comment: @nafas I have not heard that, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

the simple idea is

1. To read the file as String.
2. To check for the last char of the String , if number remove it
3. To write it back to a file

I definitely recommend you using  [apahe common IO](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.4), your life will become very easy.

sample code:

```
    File f=new File("");
    String s = FileUtils.readFileToString(f);  //read the file using common IO
    char c=s.charAt(s.length()-1);   //get the last char of your string
    if(!(c>='0' && c<='9')){           //if not number
        s=s.substring(0,s.length()-1);  //remove it
    }
    FileUtils.write(f, s);  //write back to the file  using common IO
```

**EDIT:**

You don't need to use Common IO, there are many other ways of `reading from` and `writing to` a file in java

Comment: That looks nice, but I need to keep the last character if its a number* Sorry if my wording was confusing. Would it look like

Comment: Hmm, that looks good to me I will try this out. However I have to keep the last character if it's a number, I am trying to remove a "Turn symbol" that shows up in a report, the character right behind that symbol is a number. Would it look like

Comment: @JoeValenti ok mate, now you are confusing me, I'm not quite sure what you need

Comment: Sorry; 
I have a file that is a report.
The report has credit history 
At the very end of the file there is a "Character Turn" symbol (The arrow that no one uses anymore ) 
I need to remove this symbol, because it is giving the website we upload it to, an error.

Comment: So basically, what I had originally, removed the last character, but if we to run it again it would continue removing the last character. I need it to remove the last character ONLY if the character is NOT a number.

Comment: I c. well, the code above should work, I'm not familiar with RandomAccessFile class so not quite sure how to make ur code work